# How to format negative 0 with currency NumberFormatter

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

I noticed my app is displaying "-$0.00" for a value of -0. The simple form of the math is `let balance: Double = -1 * value`. I want my negative 0 values to just display as "$0.00". Is there a way to have the NumberFormatter properly handle this?

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency

let d: Double = -1 * 0
formatter.string(from: d as NSNumber)! // -$0.00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with money, currency etc it is much better to use `Decimal` than `Double` and it will also solve your problem here, change the declaration of `d` as below

```
let d: Decimal = -1 * 0
```

and the formatter will produce "$0.00"

Answer (score 0):

My current approach is:

```
struct Formatter {

    static func currency(_ value: Double) -> String {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        let value = (value == 0) ? 0 : value // Convert -0 to 0
        return formatter.string(from: value as NSNumber) ?? ""
    }

}


Formatter.currency(-1 * 0) // $0.00
```